# Icecast change listener url YP Directory

Tags: icecast

I am looking for a solution to stop icecast publishing the icecast server listener link instead I want to publish a custom listener link that is a file hosted on our web server.

For example say the icecast server is on domain https://stream.example.com:8000/

I want if user is on icecast directory instead of seeing that as the listener URL they would be connected to https://www.example.com/stream.m3u

I don't know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on this as well, and I've gotten to this so far:

In `icecast.xml`, add this:

```
<!-- This is the hostname other people will use to connect to your server.
     It affects mainly the urls generated by Icecast for playlists and yp
     listings. You MUST configure it properly for YP listings to work!
-->
<hostname>www.example.com</hostname>
```

Also make sure you have an 80 `listen-socket`:

```
<!-- You may have multiple <listen-socket> elements -->
<listen-socket>
    <port>80</port>
</listen-socket>
```

This will get you to `http://www.example.com/{your-stream}`.  That's enough for https://dir.xiph.org to work, since it just links your stream, so your site's HTTPS redirect will function.  This isn't enough for https://www.internet-radio.com, since it actually provides a web player, but I haven't been able to get `https` into the directories yet.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, that is for Icecast 2.4.x, there is no way to publish to the YP directories using an `https` scheme for the stream URL, this will be possible in the upcoming Icecast 2.5 release.